# ASP.NET: Globalization/localization: Enumerating local resource objects

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

There's a function:

```
this.GetLocalResourceObject() as string
```

That takes a key and returns a localized string.

How can I enumerate all the local resource objects/localized strings?

Something to do with the `ResourceManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want a [ResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset(v=VS.100).aspx), which you can access through the GetResourceSet method on ResourceManager. A ResourceSet has a number of possible ways to enumerate it, iirc [GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset.getenumerator(v=VS.100).aspx) might be the most immediately helpful.